# Button operation not executing on click, instead executes after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, jsx

Beginner in React here. I'm practicing by making a simple calculator by myself. I used arrays to collect the numbers as input and output.

However, the little difference I want is to make the result dynamically update as numbers are inputed.
I've managed to come close to it, but the issue is that the result only updates with the previous input.
Some thing like:

Input: 1 + 3
Output: 1

Next input: 1 + 32
Output: 4 (From the previous input)

Next input: 1 + 32 +
Output: 33 (From the previous input)

Next input: 1 + 32 + 1
Output: Still shows 33 (From the previous input)

Here's what I've done in my code

```
import { useState } from "react";

function CalcApp() {
    const [digits, setDigits] = useState([]);
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');
    const [history, setHistory] = useState([]);
    const [historyIndex, setHistoryIndex] = useState(-1);

    let finalOutput

    function handleClearScreen() {
        setDigits([]);
        setResult('');
        setHistory([]);
        setHistoryIndex(-1);
    }

    function handleSingleDelete() {
        setDigits(prevDigits => prevDigits.slice(0, -1));
        if (history.length === 0 || historyIndex === -1) {
            setResult('');
        } else {
            setHistoryIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex - 1);
            setResult(history[historyIndex]);
        }
    }

    function handleButtonPress(value) {
        try {
            if (value === "=") {
                finalOutput = eval(digits.join('')).toString();
                setDigits([finalOutput]);
                setResult('');
            } else {
                setDigits(prevDigits => [...prevDigits, value]);

                finalOutput = eval(digits.join('')).toString();
                setResult(finalOutput);

                setHistory(prevHistory => [...prevHistory, finalOutput]);
                setHistoryIndex(prevIndex => prevIndex + 1);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <DisplayScreen
                inputValue={digits}
                outputValue={result}
            />
            <KeyPad
                handleOnClick={handleButtonPress}
                clearScreen={handleClearScreen}
                singleDelete={handleSingleDelete}
            />
        </>
    )
}

function DisplayScreen({ inputValue, outputValue }) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="calc-display">
                <InputRow inputVal={inputValue} />
                <OutputRow outputVal={outputValue} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

function InputRow({ inputVal }) {
    return (
        <div className="input-row">
            <>{inputVal}</>
        </div>
    )
}

function OutputRow({ outputVal }) {
    return (
        <div className="output-row">
            <>{outputVal}</>
        </div>
    )
}

function NumButtons({ value, onButtonPress }) {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={() => onButtonPress(value)}
        >
            {value}
        </button>
    );
}

function OpButtons({ value, onButtonPress }) {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            onClick={() => onButtonPress(value)}
        >
            {value}
        </button>
    );
}

function KeyPad({ handleOnClick, clearScreen, singleDelete }) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="key-row">
                <button className="square" value={"AC"}
                    onClick={clearScreen}>AC</button>
                <button className="square" value={"Del"}
                    onClick={singleDelete}>Del</button>

                <NumButtons />
                <OpButtons value={"+"} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
            </div>
            <div className="key-row">
                <NumButtons value={7} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={8} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={9} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <OpButtons value={"-"} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
            </div>
            <div className="key-row">
                <NumButtons value={4} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={5} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={6} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <OpButtons value={"*"} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
            </div>
            <div className="key-row">
                <NumButtons value={1} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={2} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={3} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <OpButtons value={"/"} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
            </div>
            <div className="key-row">
                <NumButtons value={"."} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons value={0} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
                <NumButtons />
                <OpButtons value={"="} onButtonPress={handleOnClick} />
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export { CalcApp, InputRow, KeyPad, DisplayScreen }
```

Comment: it seems that you're updating the result state before the new digit is added to the array of digits. As a result, the evaluation is being performed on the previous state of digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

these lines seem to cause the issue here,

```
 setDigits(prevDigits => [...prevDigits, value]);
 finalOutput = eval(digits.join('')).toString();
 setResult(finalOutput);
```

you are setting the Digits in the first line and think that the values in digit has been updated, but the value is not immediately updated with setState, so you are left with the last value that was set and that reflects in the calculations.
what you can do is `finalOutput = eval([...digits, value].join('')).toString();`
this will give you the latest value and result.
you can read this answer for better understanding [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: But I don't get why the most current result is not passed to the setHistory even though I'm passing the same finalOutput to the setHistory